# How to send object model from objective-C(In framework) to Swift (outside of framework)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have model class in one framework made in objective-C I am trying to send objective-C model class object to swift class so that I can use its values in swift (swift class is in project not in framework).

What I have done

1. Created bridging header file and import model class .h File in it.
2. also trying to create object of swift class in objective-C file so that I can pass object of model class in swift object

**Model Class**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ModelClass : NSObject{

}

@property (copy) NSString *modelString;

@end
```

**another class .m file**

creating object of model class

```
ModelClass *modelClass = [[ModelClass alloc] init];
modelClass.modelString = @"testString";
```

trying to pass this object to swift class. But I am not able to create object of swift class in objective-C file

NOTE: model class and .m file is in framework and swift class is in project

Is there any solution ?

Comment: show some code?

Comment: Please check my updated question

Comment: Do you have problems creating the object in swift or to pass it in a function to swift?

Comment: I have problem creating object of swift class in objective-C class (Objective-C class is in framework and swift class is outside of framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass objects from Objective-C to Swift you will need to include `<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h` into your Obj-C code, this header file is generated automatically by Xcode. If you have created one yourself delete it.

**Swift**

```
class Foo {
    var model: ModelClass

    // ...
}
```

**Objective-C**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "<ProductModuleName>-Swift.h"

// ...

ModelClass *modelClass = [[ModelClass alloc] init];
modelClass.modelString = @"testString";

Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
[foo setModel:modelClass];
```

I haven't tested the above code, but the principle is there.

---

**Update**

To access Swift inside an external framework in Objective-C, use `@import FrameworkName` in your `.m` file. The public Swift classes in the framework should then be accessible in Objective-C.

From Apple Doc's [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 3.0.1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH10-XID_82)

> **Importing External Frameworks**
>
> You can import external frameworks that have a pure Objective-C
>   codebase, a pure Swift codebase, or a mixed-language codebase. The
>   process for importing an external framework is the same whether the
>   framework is written in a single language or contains files from both
>   languages. When you import an external framework, make sure the
>   Defines Module build setting for the framework you’re importing is set
>   to “Yes”.

**Objective-C**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@import FrameworkName

// ...

Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];

// ...
```

---

**Another Update**

If you're awaiting results from an asynchronous method, such as returning data from a web request, you can use either `delegates` or `blocks`. These are interchangeable between Objective-C and Swift, ensuring the above requirements of mixing languages is adhered to. Below is an example for using `blocks`.

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)fetchSomething:(void (^)(ModelClass *))completion
{
    ModelClass *modelClass = [[ModelClass alloc] init];
    modelClass.modelString = @"testString";
    completion(modelClass);
}
```

**Swift**

```
foo.fetchSomething() {
    model in
    print(model.modelString)
}
```

Comment: actually the problem is my Module class and another class is in framework and the file to which i need to send that object is in swift and it outside framework . ---------------but in your answer both file are in project---------issue is in creating   Foo *foo = [[Foo alloc] init];

Comment: @sss Without clear code examples or explanation of your problem it's difficult to give you an accurate answer. I've edited the answer with importing a Swift framework into Objective-C

Comment: to keep it clear- In my swift project I have framework in objective-C , I need to create object of swift class(which is outside of framework) in frameworks objective-C class

Comment: @import is now disabled by Apple

Comment: @sss Have you set the `Defines Module` build setting to `Yes` as per the documentation quote above?

Comment: Yes I already did it YES..but why should I import framework in objective-C file which is already in framework?

Comment: @sss Right to get this clear: You are writing a framework written in Objective-C, you want to create a Swift class outside of this framework, yet reference the external Swift class from inside the framework? What I understand you're attempting to accomplish is beyond the limitations of a framework as they're self contained bundles. You need to rethink the structure of your app, frameworks can only request dependencies then include those frameworks as per above. Is the Obj-C model class inside the framework?

Comment: You got my issue correctly.... YES..Model class is inside framework...I am doing this because I am getting data from SDK(Framework) classes.....is there any other way to pass class object from framework to project class?

Comment: @sss The SDK classes are async Internet requests? If so you can use either `delegates` or `blocks`. I'll update my answer with an example.